# How to record IM conversations in Office Communicator 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, communicator

And why hasn't Microsoft built this functionality in?? Because they want to tie you into using Outlook (which does record IM conversations in conjunction with Communicator)?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality *is* built in.

IM logging is built into Outlook because that is where most businesses keep most of their communication information.  People already search for their email in Outlook; keeping IM conversations there is a natural progression and is easy for most people to understand.  Many of their users have already learned how to search Outlook for mail; keeping IM conversations there means they can search IM as well without having to learn anything new.